# In spring should you create beans for existing classes?

Tags: spring

I'm creating a spring application and I want to use an unaltered instance of SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler for use in my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class

```
.failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
```

Is it acceptable to use new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler in this instance or should I create a bean in my appconfig to return the class? I feel like I should do it via Bean but I can't explain to my colleague exactly why this is.

```
.failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler())
```

vs

```
//in appconfig
@Bean
public FailureHandler failureHandler() {
    return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
}

//back in the class
@Autowired
FailureHandler failureHandler
...
...
.failureHandler(failureHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be acceptable, but using a bean enables: declaring it once and injecting it into several clients, hides the decision of which implementation is being used from the web security configuration, and allows for mocking in tests. Whether these concerns apply to your application is up to debate with your colleagues.